# Modals are opening when already a Modal is open Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I stop other modals from appearing when there is already a modal open.

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="portfolio">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
<div class="projects">
            <div data-modal="modal1">
                <div>
                      <p>Coffee</p>
                </div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt="">
              </div>
            <div data-modal="modal2">
                <div>
                       <p>Tea</p>
                </div>
                <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/tea-cup-bag-high-res-stock-photography-1570544677.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
           <div data-modal="modal3">
                <div>
                       <p>Kava</p>
                </div>
                <img src="https://www.kanata-entreprises.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/the-tisanes.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
          </div>

<div class="project-card hidden" id="modal1">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt="">
        </div>
       </div>
        
<div class="project-card hidden" id="modal2">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/tea-cup-bag-high-res-stock-photography-1570544677.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
  <div class="project-card hidden" id="modal3">
            <button class="close">X</button>
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="https://www.kanata-entreprises.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/the-tisanes.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Here is js code to open modal:

```
const coffeeGrounds = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div[data-modal^=modal]');
const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
const allModals = document.querySelectorAll('.project-card');

// Open Modals
for (var i = 0; i < coffeeGrounds.length; i++) {
    coffeeGrounds[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var x = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
        var a = document.getElementById(x);
        a.setAttribute('style','display:block');
       
    });
}
```

Here is js code, when click outside to close the modal:

```
// when clicked outside to close the modal:
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
    if (!e.path.some(x => x.className && x.className.includes('project-card'))) {
        allModals.forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none');
    }
  }, true)
```

Please any help would be appreciated. Feel free to optimize my code.
Here is the visual representation: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/bGwpzbE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could take your close modal function, and then just apply it before you show a new modal. So the idea is -- hide all modal --> show modal x.

```
const coffeeGrounds = document.querySelectorAll('.projects > div[data-modal^=modal]');
const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
const allModals = document.querySelectorAll('.project-card');

const hideModals = (e) => {
    if (!e.path.some(x => x.className && x.className.includes('project-card'))) {
        allModals.forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none');
    }
};

// Open Modals
for (var i = 0; i < coffeeGrounds.length; i++) {
    coffeeGrounds[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        hideModals(e);
        var x = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
        var a = document.getElementById(x);
        a.setAttribute('style','display:block');
       
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this but for some reason, I cannot access .path from the function. Can you apply this on Jsfiddle or Codepen.

Comment: Sorry I slightly misguided you. In my example I did not passed the event down.

Comment: Edited the above ^ Also codepen example: https://codepen.io/POWERGLOVE/pen/qBaNPwz

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't quite solve my problem. Models are still appearing on click.

Comment: Just to be clarified,  an expected workflow is click on 'coffee', the coffee modal appears. Click on 'tea', 'coffee' modal hides, and 'tea' modal appears? This flow is valid, and is it working? Or is there another issue? Thanks

Comment: This flow is alright, but I want a modal to not open when already a modal is open. I don't want the user to experience unexpected behavior outside the modals.

Comment: One other possibility I was thinking that when user clicks anywhere on the window, the already opened modal closes, eventually this will stop the other modal to open on click.

Comment: ^ Updated Codepen. From my understanding you are describing a mask. I added one in the example. So behind the active modal is an active mask. It's a cover that blocks all interaction with things in the background until it is disabled. Only when it is closed, you can interact again. Is this experience the expectation? Re attached link for example: https://codepen.io/POWERGLOVE/pen/qBaNPwz

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want. I didn't know about the mask before is it an CSS feature?

Comment: Glad to hear! It's more of a concept than an actual feature. So in short, it's like creating an invisible modal that covers the whole page, but sits behind the actual modal you are interacting with. What it does is creates an invisible wall so that mouse events do not penetrate beyond it. Similar alternative to using event.stopPropagation() in JavaScript.

Comment: It's working flawlessly on codepen but when I copy the same code in my text editor it's throwing me an error that it can't read the property of 'addEventListener' of a null (that is set on getElementById('mask')) and the same error on 'mask.setAttribute'. I don't what's wrong.

Comment: oops, my bad I forgot to add a div element for the mask in HTML. No errors but it isn't working. Is there something that I might be missing?

Comment: This issue might be on my side I will keep working on this. Thank you again for helping and introducing me to the new concept. Really appreciate it.

Comment: It's working now I forgot to add the mask styling. I will dig into this more though, Thanks a lot.